# Does Blinding Cloud not affect Widow Mines?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it true that Blinding Cloud doesn't affect Widow Mines?

If so, why wouldn't it? Are mines not counted as units or is this simply a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the widow mine "attack" is in fact an ability. For the same reason you can storm out of a blinding cloud, a widow mine can "attack"
http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=401882

Answer (score 5):

As Hugo mentions, the Widow Mine "attack" is an auto-cast ability.

I tested this in-game; Blinding Cloud will not save you from their husband-killing ways.

[image]